# How to handle new branch in `pre-receive` git script?

Tags: git, githooks

I have script to block unresolved merge conflicts to be pushed:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "pre-receive HOOK: $old_sha $new_sha"

while read old_sha new_sha refname
do

if git diff "$old_sha" "$new_sha" | grep -qE '^\+(<<<<<<<|>>>>>>>)'; then
    echo "Saw a conflict marker in $(basename "$refname")."
    git diff "$old_sha" "$new_sha" | grep -nE '^\+(<<<<<<<|>>>>>>>)'
    exit 1
fi

done

exit 0
```

But when new branch is pushed I get next error message:

**fatal: bad object 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000**

Full output:

```
Counting objects: 77, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (58/58), done.
Writing objects: 100% (77/77), 11.27 KiB | 5.63 MiB/s, done.
Total 77 (delta 52), reused 14 (delta 6)
remote: pre-receive HOOK
remote: fatal: bad object 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
To https://tracker.feel-safe.net/gitdev/main.git
 * [new branch]        296-ToS-component -> xxx
```

And, as you can see, broken changes are committed.

**How to handle new branche in `pre-receive` hook?**

Should I create `update` hook instead?

Answer (score 3):

When a new ref is created, `old_sha` is equal to `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`. This hash doesn't have a real object so `git diff` can't work properly. If you need the diff, use `git diff 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 $new_sha` instead. `4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904` is the hash of the empty tree which can work without a real object.

You need to deal with another similar case, in which a ref is deleted and `new_sha` is `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`. Similarily, use `git diff $old_sha 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904` to get the diff.

You could see `pre-push.sample` under `.git/hooks` for reference. It's a good sample that shows how to deal with creating, deleting and updating a ref, except that `pre-receive` takes no arguments while `pre-push` takes two. But both can read something from standard input.

Comment: While this will work, `git diff 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 $new_sha` will output the entire difference between `$new_sha` and the empty tree, which can be a lot if you repository is quite big/old. A better solution would be to diff between the commit from which the branch originated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did:

I assumed that whenever we have a commit on a new branch, the hash for the old_sha would be `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`. If that is the case then I traverse up from new_sha until I get a parent that has a refname (branch name) that differs from the one received in the hook, and I make that parent my old_sha instead and continue as normal.

```sh
        # Check if old_sha is 0000..., if so then a new branch happened, so we need to point old_sha to revision on the parent branch
        if [[ "$old_sha" == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" ]]; then
            # point old_sha to the parent revision (commit)
            old_sha="$(git rev-parse $new_sha^)"
            # get the branch name (refname) of the parent
            parent_refname="$(git name-rev $old_sha --name-only)"
            # Travers up until old_sha is the commit (revision) on the parent branch
            while [ "$parent_refname" == "$refname" ]
            do
                old_sha="$(git rev-parse $old_sha^)"
                parent_refname="$(git name-rev $old_sha --name-only)"
            done
        fi
```

So I would put this block of code right above your `if` statement.

I have just tested this once now and I'm no expert in git nor bash, so please feel free to point out any case(s) where this will cause problems.

Comment: this is a pretty good solution. but it has one drawback. if the parent branch is also not pushed.
using `git branch --contains <old SHA>` instead of checking names will ensure the parent commit is one that was already committed before.
notice i don't use `-r` since pre-receive is run on the remote.